# Typescript property returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel

I have encountered very weird behavior using angular model when user selects from an option. I will provide screenshots + code snippets. In summary, I am getting undefined for property that is populated. Model object returns expected string but if I directly call the property, it returns undefined.

Object that contains all properties, followed by direct call:

[image]

[image]

```
<ng-template>
   <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Source Name :</label>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select [(ngModel)]="opcoReference.opcoRef.tntSourceName" class="form-control form-control-sm">
         <option *ngFor="let object of opcoReference.origSourceName" [ngValue]="object.code">{{object.desc}}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hover over that `i` in the blue box...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your actual question, what is happening is `tntSourceName` is `undefined` at the time of the console log and then set later.

The reason it's confusing is because your first `console.log()` is passed a reference to the object, and the value in the console changes as the object changes. If you want to see the value at that instant try using JSON stringify then JSON parse, and you will see `tntSourceName` is `undefined` at the time of the log.

Edit: either of the other two answer should help you prevent errors in your code resulting from `tntSourceName` being `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

From your screen I don't see that `opcoReference.origSourceName` exists.

But if this is not the case then probably data is not ready when it is rendering. Try to use this

```
<ng-template>
   <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Source Name :</label>
   <div class="col-sm-2" *ngIf="opcoReference">
      <select [(ngModel)]="opcoReference.opcoRef?.tntSourceName" class="form-control form-control-sm">
         <option *ngFor="let object of opcoReference.origSourceName" [ngValue]="object.code">{{object.desc}}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just from the browser console lazy loading the object properties. ie. they are not loaded until you expand the object in the debugger. Perhaps you want to wait for `tntSourceName` to be populated before rendering the `select`?

```html
<div class="col-sm-2" *ngIf="opcoReference.opcoRef.tntSourceName">
      <select [(ngModel)]="opcoReference.opcoRef.tntSourceName" class="form-control form-control-sm">
         <option *ngFor="let object of opcoReference.origSourceName" [ngValue]="object.code">{{object.desc}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
```